# Properly format JSON data in jQuery suggest

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

Following the example [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-jQuery-Autocomplete-using-Web-Service-in-ASP.Net.aspx), I have been able to create a webservice to return JSON to my jQuery autosuggest textbox.

I can get the data but it seems to be in a **weird format** in the drop down area. 
**It displays as ["Example 1, "Example2] and is stacked vertically, rather than each Name being stacked horizontally like they should.** I am serializing my data in the webservice with JSON and returning json rather than a string. That may have something to do with it, or could it be the type of format being returned in my javascript?

**Here is the script on my web forms..**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#<%=ClientSearch.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/GetClients.asmx/GetClientNames") %>',
                data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.split('-')[0],
                            val: item.split('-')[1]
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (e, i) {
            $("#<%=hfClientID.ClientID %>").val(i.item.val);
        },
        minLength: 1
    });
 });
</script>
```

**Finally, here is the web service..**

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetClientNames(string prefix)
{
    List<string> clients = new List<string>();
    using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Name], [ID] FROM [Current] WHERE " + "[Name] LIKE " + "'" + prefix + "%'";
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            SqlCeDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                clients.Add(string.Format("{0}-{1}", sdr["Name"], sdr["ID"]));
            }

            conn.Close();
        }
        string json = js.Serialize(clients);
        return json;
    }
}
```

I've got through the autocomplete documentation at the jquery website but I just cant seem to format the data how I need it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show your example of data ?

Comment: @minhcat_vo
The data is queried from an SQL database.
There is a table called [Current], containing various rows. One particular row is call [Name] and this is what my web service queries. 
The should be formatted like..

Marriott - Omaha

but it instead
["Marriott - Omaha"], stacked vertically and each letter is as it's own separate item in the dropdown list.

Comment: In the web service - `clients.Add(string.Format("{0}-{1}", sdr["Name"], sdr["ID"]));`

In jquery - `                            return {
                                label: item.split('-')[0],
                                val: item.split('-')[1]
                            }`
The data binds to an <asp:Hiddenfield>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you manually JSON serializing? You shouldn't be. Get rid of this `JavaScriptSerializer` and:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<string> GetClientNames(string prefix)
{
    List<string> clients = new List<string>();
    using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Name], [ID] FROM [Current] WHERE " + "[Name] LIKE " + "'" + prefix + "%'";
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            SqlCeDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                clients.Add(string.Format("{0}-{1}", sdr["Name"], sdr["ID"]));
            }

            conn.Close();
        }
        return clients;
    }
}
```

Comment: Splendid. I was trying various methods and another user had suggested that I serialize the data. 
I have used the original code from the example mentioned earlier but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: I get the correct format now but there are certain names that contain hyphens and the first part of the name will display but the rest doesn't. Probably something to do with the hyphen it's self. Example..Marriott - Omaha, I just get Marriott.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this :

```
while(sdr.Read) 
{
    clients = clients.Add(string.Format("[{0}-{1}]", sdr["Name"], sdr["ID"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do the split. Using a hyphen isn't safe as your data could contain them.

```html
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public List<ItemModel> GetVendors(string prefix)
        {
            var vendors = new List<ItemModel>();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConn"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NAME, VEND_ID FROM VENDORS WHERE NAME LIKE @SearchText + '%'" + " ORDER BY NAME";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefix.ToUpper().Trim());
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            var item = new ItemModel()
                            {
                                Name = sdr["NAME"].ToString(),
                                ID = (int)sdr["VEND_ID"]
                            };
                            vendors.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
                return vendors;
            }
        }
```

And then in your script:

```html
success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.Name,
                                val: item.ID
                            }
                        }))
                    },
```